# mvnw file throwing error in windows while building docker image

Tags: spring, spring-boot, docker, maven, maven-plugin

I have a spring-boot project which was created on mac and pushed to github, I am cloning it on my windows 10 laptop, and trying to build docker image by referring to **Multi-Stage Build** https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-boot-docker/

here while running the Dockerfile I am getting following error:

```
 ---> Running in 4ae632bc1c4b
/bin/sh: ./mvnw: /bin/sh^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I know that **dos2unix.exe mvnw** will fix the issue, but just wanted to know why this is happening, I am not editing the mvnw file on my windows and still it is having some windows line endings.

Comment: You cloned with git under windows?

Comment: yes, I cloned using gitbash terminal

Comment: Either you have the characters in your git repository, or your git is configured to use windows endings for text files.

Comment: I could see core.autocrlf=true in my git config, so is that making the problem?

Comment: Tell git to treat this file as a binary file and clone again.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing the encoding of the /mvnw file to UTF8 - LF. After this I was able to generate the image without problem.